# Lots of queries on one page that take too long to execute... Can't seem to optimize them

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, subquery

I got a blog where I track who views what post and when by inserting an entry into a table (`views`) with the visitor's IP, the post ID (I got a primary key on those fields) and a timestamp.

This table is then used to display the top 5 posts for each of my categories (got 4 of them) for the last day/week/month/year and all-time. So, that's a total of 20 queries executing, each of them taking somewhere between 0.2 and 0.7 seconds... My page takes a little more than 7 seconds to load, which is awful.

Here some useful information about my database structure :

```
+---------------------+        +----------------------+
|   posts (82 rows)   |        |   views (50k rows)   |
+=====================+        +======================+
|    id (primary)     |        |     ip (primary)     |
+---------------------+        +----------------------+
|        type         |        | article_id (primary) |
+---------------------+        +----------------------+
|     thumbnail       |        |     date (index)     |
+---------------------+        +----------------------+
|    title (index)    |       
+---------------------+
|         url         |
+---------------------+
| description (index) |
+---------------------+
|       content       | 
+---------------------+
|        date         |
+---------------------+
|       lastmod       |
+---------------------+
|       sources       |
+---------------------+
|        tags         |
+---------------------+
|      published      |
+---------------------+
|         ...         |
+---------------------+
```

The `...` represent the additional fields for the English versions of my posts (`url_en`, `title_en`, `description_en`, `tags_en`, and `content_en`).

Here's one of my huge queries (they're all basically the same):

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, p.url, tmp.cnt AS views
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, article_id -- 0.34s
           FROM views
           WHERE article_id IN (SELECT id
                                FROM posts
                                WHERE id <> 12 AND type = 'Tutoriel') AND 
                 date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW() -- the 01-01-2013 is normally a variable but for testing purposes I've replaced it with a fixed date here
           GROUP BY article_id
           ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 5) AS tmp 
       ON p.id = tmp.article_id
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT article_id
               FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, article_id -- 0.34s
                     FROM views
                     WHERE article_id IN (SELECT id
                                          FROM posts
                                          WHERE id <> 12 AND type = 'Tutoriel')
                       AND date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW()
                     GROUP BY article_id
                     ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 5) AS tmp2 
              )
ORDER BY views DESC
```

I figured out that the `BETWEEN` clause is what is taking most of the time, since I got this same exact query for all-time stats for all posts (so, not category nor date dependant) an that one only takes .03 seconds to execute.

I've looked at this query in all possible ways and couldn't find a simpler and more optimized way to write it... Yet, I feel there has to be a way. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious here.

One thing that bugs me is my duplicate subquery. I didn't find any other way to fetch both my post data and the number of associated views.

What I am thinking of is maybe doing AJAX requests for each period when the user clicks on the tab for that period (it's a tabbed view). However, that doesn't really solve the problem, it just feels like a dirty workaround.

I could maybe partition my `posts` table in one of the following ways:

- one table for the French version and another one for the English one
- one table for the commonly accessed fields (`title`, `description`, `url`) and another one for the rest
- combination of the above

This could speed it up a little if I'm not mistaken.

Could anyone give me some advice on this? By the way, thanks for bearing with me until here :)

Comment: You have not told us anything about indexes or the amount of data.  Since this is a very involved question you might want to create an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Sorry about that, editing in a minute.

Comment: Right, forgot to edit the name in my query. Those are indeed the same tables. Edited just now.

Comment: Adding an index to type will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of MySQL are particularly inept at optimizing `in` with a subquery.  Try using `join` instead:

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, p.url, tmp.cnt AS views
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, article_id -- 0.34s
           FROM views
           WHERE article_id IN (SELECT id
                                FROM posts
                                WHERE id <> 12 AND type = 'Tutoriel') AND 
                 date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW() -- the 01-01-2013 is normally a variable but for testing purposes I've replaced it with a fixed date here
           GROUP BY article_id
           ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 5) AS tmp 
       ON p.id = tmp.article_id join
          (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, article_id -- 0.34s
           FROM views v join
                (SELECT id
                 FROM posts p
                 WHERE p.id <> 12 AND p.type = 'Tutoriel'
                ) p
                on v.article_id = p.id
            WHERE v.date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW()
            GROUP BY v.article_id
            ORDER BY cnt DESC
            LIMIT 5
           ) a
       on p.id = a.article_id
ORDER BY views DESC
```

EDIT:

If I understand the query correctly, you can just change your `left outer join` to a `join` and eliminate the `where` clause entirely:

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, p.url, tmp.cnt AS views
FROM posts Ap JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, article_id -- 0.34s
      FROM views
      WHERE article_id IN (SELECT id
                           FROM posts
                           WHERE id <> 12 AND type = 'Tutoriel') AND 
            date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW() -- the 01-01-2013 is normally a variable but for testing purposes I've replaced it with a fixed date here
     GROUP BY article_id
     ORDER BY cnt DESC
     LIMIT 5
    ) tmp 
    ON p.id = tmp.article_id;
```

And then change the `in` in the subquery to a join:

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, p.url, tmp.cnt AS views
FROM posts Ap JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, article_id -- 0.34s
      FROM views v join
           (SELECT distinct p.id  -- distinct may not be necessary
            FROM posts p
            WHERE p.id <> 12 AND p.type = 'Tutoriel'
           ) p
           on v.rticle_id = p.id
      WHERE date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW() -- the 01-01-2013 is normally a variable but for testing purposes I've replaced it with a fixed date here
     GROUP BY article_id
     ORDER BY cnt DESC
     LIMIT 5
    ) tmp 
    ON p.id = tmp.article_id;
```

Comment: Nice one here. Got it down to .02 seconds. Combined with what itachi42 said, it got down to .0004 seconds. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it would help but if `BETWEEN` takes a lot of time, maybe turn it into an other condition ?

```
date BETWEEN 01-01-2013 AND NOW()
```

to

```
date > 01-01-2013
```

So it won't have to compare two dates, and it will always be between 01-01-2013 and NOW

Comment: True... I'll try that out to see if it helps.

Comment: Sped up my query like hell. Gone from 0.60s to 0.03s. My query is still ugly as hell though, so I'm gonna give a try at what Gordon Linoff said above.